# Getting this {"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null} instead of a Number in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm trying to make a function that returns a time difference between a server timestamp field's value and an instant client timestamp! When I try to the log the result to the console it works fine

[image]

BUT!! when I want to return that int result .. it shows this "{"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}" !!! do you have any suggestion why this is happening ?

I tried some of non-sense solutions and nothing worked for me!

Comment: Please include code as text in the question rather than as an image of it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`loggingTimeDifference` is an **async** function, so it'll always [return a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value).
To get actual result you have to either await it or chain callback to the promise.

Call with awaiting would look like this:

```js
const result = await loggingTimeDifference();  
console.log(result);
```

And chaining:

```js
loggingTimeDifference().then((result) => console.log(result));
```